# cucumber-js reporting service with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cucumber, report, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am looking to have my `Cypress` test reports published to the Cucumber Reports service(https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/?lang=javascript)

We use `Cypress` with `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.

Have the following config:

```
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/e2e/",
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  },
```

`cypress/cucumber-json` folder has .cucumber.json files  and I expected it to be used on running

```
cucumber-js --publish
```

It does publish a report but with 0 specs i.e

```
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.001s (executing steps: 0m00.000s)
```